# How to remove PHP cookie in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cookies

I am tried last two hour but not deleting PHP cookies in JavaScript code.

Here is my code:

**index.html:**

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="test();">Set Cookie</a>

function test(){
 $.ajax({
     url:'ajax.php',
     method: 'post',
     data: data,
     success: function(response){
        //success code here
     }
  });
}

if(getCookie('redirect')){
   removeCookie('redirect');
}
```

**AJAX.php:**

```
setcookie('redirect', 'Hello', time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 1);
```

**script.js:**

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function removeCookie(name) {
    alert(getCookie(name));
    document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
}
```

I have posted my all code. But my cookies are not deleted. Each time I am getting `Hello` while I am refreshing my page.

Comment: I think there are HTTP only cookies that you can't access with javascript. May be you are trying to delete HTTP ONLY cookies.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj If i accessed PHP cookie in javascript. Then why I will not delete that cookie?

Comment: Ok, makes sense. If you are able to access it using javascript, then it would not be http only.  I just mentioned a possible reason.

Comment: Do a search before asking a question

Comment: Not enough known. Provide [mcve]. All you have shown is that you remove  cookie on page load and ajax sets a cookie after that